# Задача про функции

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, с задачей. Задача про Функции. у меня в коде ошибка, видимо неправильно понял задачу:

```
n = int(input())
m = n
def f(n):
    if n == 0:
        print(0)
    elif 2 > n > 0:
        print(1)
    if n > 1:
        n %= 2
        if n == 1:
            print((m+1)//2)
        else:
            print(m//2)
f(n)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я, вероятно, совсем забыл математику. Какое-то странное определение функции. А в курсе не было какой-то темы по подобным определениям? Если да, то рекомендую дать ссылку.

Comment: Если вы про мой код, можете на него даже не смотреть. Он скорее всего неправильный

Comment: Я про сам Фоксфорд. Не понимаю про n=2n и т.д. Или где такие определения описаны?

Comment: ксажелению нету ссылки на тему

Comment: точнее ссылка есть. но само задание

Comment: но на само задание

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот прямо по написанному определению:

```
def f(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    if n%2:
        return f(n//2) + f(1 + n//2)
    else:
        return f(n//2)

n = int(input())
print(f(n))
```

Это довольно долго может считаться, поскольку такая организация рекурсии приводит к многократному вычислению одних и тех же значений. (Для n<1000 это неважно)

Но их можно записывать в список и брать оттуда, когда нужно. А можно пойти и от начала, вычисляя последовательно f(2), f(3) и так до нужного значения.

Comment: а можно с вводом, но за ответ спасибо

Comment: А ввод вы умеете делать

Comment: не понимаю форму их записи - а почему мы n//2 делаем при нечетном n? Что это вообще такое?

Comment: n = int(input()), ну я не совсем тупой)

Comment: @Сергей целочисленное деление

Comment: @user504877 Это у меня не вопрос был, а утверждение - ввод вы знаете как делать, осталось `print(f(n))`

Comment: Я знаю, что такое целочисленное  деление. Почему f(2n+1) = f(n) + f(n+1) в `f(n//2) + f(1 + n//2)` преобразовалось?

Comment: cпасибо за ответ, в вводом сделал, галочку поставил

Comment: @Сергей Может быть, вас смущает  путаница в разных n в формуле и в коде. Если входной параметр назвать k, то k=2n+1 или k=2n для чётных, тогда n=k//2

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант с [мемоизацией](https://python-course.eu/advanced-python/memoization-decorators.php):

```py
def memo(f):
    ret = {}
    def helper(i):
        if i not in ret:
            ret[i] = f(i)
        return ret[i]
    return helper

@memo
def f(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return f(n // 2) + (n % 2) * f(n // 2 + n % 2)
    
n = int(input())
print(f(n))
```